# Ubuntu VM environment whereis wpa_supplicant

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I am following certain instructions in a Ubuntu VM environment. It says to modify a "wpa_supplicant.conf" file. The first command is:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
```

However, in this location this tool does not exist. Then I did a:

```
whereis wpa_supplicant
```

It gives me 2 places (see the following screenshot):

[image]

Which location should I choose? What is the difference?

Comment: I'd note in a lot of newer wireless drivers, you may not need to use wpa_supplicant - you can just use network manager or simply have the information in /etc/networks. This may end up saving a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `whereis` to locate wpa_supplicant.conf, because, as the man says:

```
  whereis - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command
```

and wpa_supplicant.conf is not a command, just a file. You can locate it by means of the `find` command, like this:

```
 find / -type f -name wpa_supplicant.conf -print
```

to which my Kubuntu system replies

```
 # find / -type f -name wpa_supplicant.conf -print
 /etc/dbus-1/system.d/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

If your copy of wpa_supplicant.conf is not in /etc/dbus-1/system.d, the above command will tell you its correct location.

Answer (score 0):

In this configuration file, the `ctrl_interface` is not the location of a binary file you should provide to wpa_supplicant, but rather the location of where it should store some files other programs such as `wpa_gui` or `wpa_cli` use to communicate with `wpa_supplicant`.

So it's perfectly natural this location doesn't exist if `wpa_supplicant` is not running, the program will create it when started.

`/var/run/wpa_supplicant` is the classic location. You don't need to change it, except in really special cases.